# Size changing paragraphs in web page

Tags: html, dynamic, web

I'm a bit new to web dev, I want to have a box with text in it that can change sizes with an + or - without reloading the page it's in. How could I do that?

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript for this, seen some answers here that pertains to jQuery, in case you wonder, it is a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can change properties of some elements, like the font-size.

look this example : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-the-jquery-ui-to-control-the-size-of-your-text/

Comment: yes, but for this you have many techniques. like put a div in front of this text, or replace the text by nothing (and store in memory).

Comment: @user1060828 To hide the text, have it encapsulated in a separate div and then use javascript to change the style to display: block / display:none to show/hide it - cleaner & easier than physically hiding it or having to "remember" the text after removing it.

Comment: there is a jquery plugin for this? @FluffyKitten

Comment: For show/hide? If you're using jquery you can use .show() .hide() .toggle() functions, you don't need a plugin for those

Comment: I don't understand...? You can use .show() & .hide() to hide part of the text, just wrap it in a div or span and show or hide it

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj see link in the comment of my answer below for a working example

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Czauu/):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="textdiv">This is the text that will change size</div>
<a href="#" id="increase">+</a>       <!-- link to increase size -->
<a href="#" id="decrease">-</a>       <!-- link to decrease size -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#textdiv{ font-size:1em;}             <!-- You MUST set initial font-size -->
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       //code is only executed when page is fully loaded

    $("#increase").click(function(){                // triggered when the #increase link is clicked
        size = parseFloat($('#textdiv').css('font-size'), 10);  //get current size
        $('#textdiv').css('font-size', size*1.2);   // increase size
        return false;                               // prevent the link action
    });

    $("#decrease").click(function(){                 // #decrease link is clicked
        size = parseFloat($('#textdiv').css('font-size'), 10); //get current size
        $('#textdiv').css('font-size', size*0.8);    //decrease size
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This version of the code also implements show/hide on text, as you asked in a previous comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Czauu/1/

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.

A simple line like this, can achieve what you want:

```
$(function() {
    size = 10;
    $('#bigger').live('click', function() {
        size++;
        $('p').css('font-size', size + "px");
    });
    $('#smaller').live('click', function() {
        size--;
        $('p').css('font-size', size + "px");
    });
});​
```

See live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sEA2P/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to implement it.
Basically, you need to do something like this:

```
var plus_btn = $("#increase"),
    minus_btn = $("#decrease"),
    contents = $("#box > p"),
    size;

size = parseInt(contents.css("font-size")); //current font-size

plus_btn.click("click",function(e){
    size++;
    contents.css("font-size",size+"px");

});
minus_btn.click("click",function(e){
    size--;
    contents.css("font-size",size+"px");   
});
```

I wrote a small smaple in jsfiddle, you can check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zhujy_8833/RfPwY/)